# Is there a way to write fewer accessors on reactive forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am working with a reactive form, and that form has 20 inputs. For example one is like this

```
      <input formControlName="name" matInput>
```

So now for every input I need to write an accessor. Something like this

```
 get nameControl(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.get('name');
  }
```

But I need to make 20 functions for every input. Is there a faster way to do this, since accessors do not take arguments?

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? The whole thing is with formbuild.group but it still should have accessors

Comment: Why you need so many accessors? for validation?

Comment: Yeah. Validation, disable etc. I tried using on html : this.myForm.get('name') but looks kinda mess

Comment: Actually here is a great sample of general validation via reactive form.https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-ReactiveForms/blob/master/APM/src/app/products/product-edit.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehy,

if i understood the question well, would be enough to define a single method that accepts the `fieldName`:

```
getControl(name: string): AbstractControl {
 return this.form.get(name);
}
```

Or if you want to check if a control has specific you can write something like that in the component:

```
hasError(fieldName: string, errorLabel: string): boolean {
 return this.form.controls[fieldName].errors[errorLabel] !== undefined;
}
```

and in the template:

```
<p *ngIf="hasError('surname', 'required')" class="message is-danger">
  The surname is mandatory
</p>
```

to show the error